# Data-tier .bacpac import keeps failing

Tags: sql-server, ssms, import, docker, data-tier-application

Within a container, I have SqlServer running in a docker container. It was created like so:

`docker run -e "ACCEPT_EULA=Y" -e "MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD=$1" -p 1433:1433 --name sql1 -v sql1-sqlvolume:/var/opt/mssql -d mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2017-latest`

I then use SSMS to import a data-tier application. Then in the wizard I import from disk and verify all the data until it then runs the import.

With Sql Server Settings:

```
Data file path: /var/opt/mssql/data
Log file path: /var/opt/mssql/data
```

But every time, it fails with this:

```
Creating database on target - Success
Importing database - Error
Creating deployment plan - Error
Initializing deployment - Error
Refreshing Object Exporer - Success
```

The Error is:

```
===================================

Object reference not set to an instance of an object. (Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql)

------------------------------
Program Location:

at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.Deployment.SqlDeploymentPlanGenerator.DeploymentScriptDomGenerator.GenerateFragment(Int32 operation, IModelElement element)
at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.Deployment.SqlDeploymentPlanGenerator.DeploymentScriptDomGenerator.GenerateSteps(Int32 operation, IModelElement element)
at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.Deployment.OrderedStepGenerator.Add(DeploymentScriptDomGenerator scriptDom, IModelElement element, Int32 operation)
at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.Deployment.Analyzers.PlanMediator.BuildDependencyOrderedSteps(Int32 operation, List`1 classOrder, List`1 operationOrder, Dictionary`2 changes, Boolean preserveGraphs, Dictionary`2& relating, Dictionary`2& related)
at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.Deployment.Analyzers.PlanMediator.BuildOperations()
at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.Deployment.SqlDeploymentPlanGenerator.OnGeneratePlan()
at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.Deployment.SqlDeploymentPlanGenerator.GeneratePlan(List`1 drops)
at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.Deployment.SqlDeployment.BuildPlan()
at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.Deployment.SqlDeployment.Controller.CreatePlan()
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.DeployOperation.<>c__DisplayClass3.<>c__DisplayClass5.<CreatePlanInitializationOperation>b__1()
at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.Dac.OperationLogger.Capture(Action action)
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.DeployOperation.<>c__DisplayClass3.<CreatePlanInitializationOperation>b__0(Object operation, CancellationToken token)
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.Operation.Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.IOperation.Run(OperationContext context)
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.ReportMessageOperation.Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.IOperation.Run(OperationContext context)
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.OperationExtension.CompositeOperation.Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.IOperation.Run(OperationContext context)
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.OperationExtension.CompositeOperation.Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.IOperation.Run(OperationContext context)
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.DeployOperation.Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.IOperation.Run(OperationContext context)
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.OperationExtension.Execute(IOperation operation, DacLoggingContext loggingContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.DacServices.InternalDeploy(IPackageSource packageSource, Boolean isDacpac, String targetDatabaseName, DacDeployOptions options, CancellationToken cancellationToken, DacLoggingContext loggingContext, Action`3 reportPlanOperation, Boolean executePlan)
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.DacServices.ImportBacpac(BacPackage package, String targetDatabaseName, DacImportOptions importOptions, Nullable`1 cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.DacServices.ImportBacpac(BacPackage package, String targetDatabaseName, DacAzureDatabaseSpecification creationDefaults, Nullable`1 cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Dac.DacWizard.ImportDatabase.DoWork()
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.TaskForms.SimpleWorkItem.Run()
```

Can anybody see what I am doing wrong here?

======

UPDATE: The .bacpac is created from a db running in Azure Cloud. This also happens when using 2019-latest.

Comment: I'm seeing this issue as well. Not running in a container, but natively in Windows 10.

Tools info:

SQL Server Management Studio      15.0.18330.0
SQL Server Management Objects (SMO)      16.100.37971.0
Microsoft Analysis Services Client Tools      15.0.19040.0
Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC)      10.0.19041.1
Microsoft MSXML      3.0 6.0 
Microsoft .NET Framework      4.0.30319.42000
Operating System      10.0.19041

Comment: There is [this bug report](https://github.com/microsoft/azuredatastudio/issues/9522) which is for Azure Data Studio but may be of assistance if you exported the BACPAC using version 18.4.1 of SqlPackage.exe to export the BACPAC. Try downgrading to an earlier version of SqlPackage.exe (use an earlier version of SSMS) to re-export the DB and see if the new BACPAC works.

Comment: The BACPAC comes from Azure SQL, so I don't know which version of `SqlPackage` is used out there, but I don't have the option to downgrade it.